# mvn -version is displaying -bash: /usr/local/bin/mvn: No such file or directory. Any idea how I can fix this?

Tags: java, bash, maven, osx-mavericks

I was trying to upgrade from Maven 2 to Maven 3.1 on os x mavericks.  I tried using `brew install maven`, thinking it would upgrade maven to the latest version. However that didnt help. It showed the same `No such file or directory` message. Following this,I uninstalled the maven(installed through brew) by doing `brew rm maven`.

However, now I cannot seem to get back either version of maven when I try `mvn -v`, I get thhe output 
`-bash: /usr/local/bin/mvn: No such file or directory`

The following is the content of my `bash_profile`

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-2.2.1/
export JBOSS_HOME=/Applications/whp-jboss-cluster-5
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/

export TOMCAT_HOME=/Library/Tomcat/
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin:$JBOSS_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME:$TOMCAT_HOME
```

Any idea on how I can fix this and get to maven 3 would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you launched a new terminal since editing your bash_profile?

Comment: Where was maven installed previously?

Comment: Running `hash -d mvn` or `hash -r` might help with that (if only that shell instance has the problem).

Comment: @JoshBerry: Thanks, the new terminal got me back to maven 2.2.1, but how do I get to  3.1.x without screwing up again?

Comment: Should be pretty much this, but with a M3_home will be fine.

Comment: Also, if you didn't want to restart the shell, you could have "sourced" your profile and things would probably be how you want.  @EtanReisner's suggestion for `hash -r` could also be the problem you were having with your previous efforts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have all of the necessary ingredients.  You simply need to source your profile so that those changes take effect.  (You can do this with `. ~/.bash_profile`.)

It is possible that your shell cached a previous version of `mvn`.  This can happen if you add an item to your path after something of the same name has been used before.  In that case, as Etan pointed out in the comments, you can just `hash -r`, to clear things up.  (This doesn't seem to be what you were seeing, but is worth trying in the future if you add maven 3 and `mvn -version` keeps showing version 2.)

To get Maven 3 running, it should just be these steps.  Just, with your path having the maven 3 directory instead of the maven 2 one.

Comment: I was trying to delete an old maven version when I faced this issue. the hash -r solved the problem for me after deleting the mvn folders. +1